# Nuxt + Github Pages assets

Tags: javascript, vue.js, github, nuxt.js, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a small nuxt application on github pages and I'm running into trouble with my assets.

In my project I have an `assets` folder with the following structure :

```
├───css
|    └── tailwind.css
└───img
     ├── img-1.jpg
     └── img-2.jpg
```

As specified in the Nuxt docs I've added the following code to my `nuxt.config.js` :

```
  export default {
     // ...
     target: 'static',
     router: {
        base: '/<my-github-repository-name>/'
     }
  }
```

The `nuxt generate` command is running fine, I have everything at the right place and yet, once deployed on github using the `gh-pages` package, my images don't load. The funny thing is that when I look at the requests to fetch the assets the URL is right:

`https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPOSITORY>/_nuxt/img/img-1.8474c58.png`

But the request still throws a 404 error and my images are not displayed. The branch Github uses to build the page has the assets under the same path as specified in the request, and the tailwind stuff is still working so the problem is kinda hard for me to grasp...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve the problem? I'm experiencing the same thing after deploying my first Nuxt app to Github Pages. Apart from missing img/font assets, also some of the required Javascript doesn't seem to load for me and so some of the functionalities are missing

Comment: I am also facing a similar problem with github pages. have you resolved the issue already?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the resource failure is that, .nojekyll file is not moved / deployed into your github pages. So I made a small change in the package.json with the following,

package.json

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist --dotfiles"
```

Now my project is working fine without any problem after .nojekyll file is deployed into my github pages.

NOTE: .nojekyll file was generated by nuxt generate command which was available under /dist folder